# What subject or area can show the relationship between programming and networking?

Tags: network-programming

Hi I am studying Software Engineering, and I have to do a case study of relationships between network and programming, but I don't know anything about networking, I don't know where to start.

If anyone could help me out to point me to the right direction, would be great!.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to know about networking in any detail. I'd believe that you are being asked to think about how programming for a network environment generates specific conditions that need to be coded for, such as disconnected operation, bandwidth issues, and intermittant connection (how code needs to cope with an unreliable connection). I hope that helps.